# how to solve FAILURE: Build failed with an exception after configuration with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\File.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b48eb12e4a1386bfe3aa0e9022526428\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1

```js
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30// flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.digitalpartner.ineed"
        minSdkVersion 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 30 //flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle file snippet?

Comment: updated snippet